# Strange PCB Connector I haven't Seen Before - What is it?

Tags: connector, identification, plug, socket

I'm trying to determine what connector this guy is, but I've never seen it before.

[image]

It has two rows of seven pins, and they are offset a bit.

More importantly, does anyone have any tips on matching sockets? Trying to navigate through the sixty million parts / black and white pictures of sockets is really challenging.

Comment: I know these connectors... Synapticon modules are using these...

Comment: Würth WR-MM 690157001472

Comment: New one from wurth

Comment: AMP/Tyco Micromatch is the original manufacturer of these. I like them as they are quite low profile, plus you can crimp them without special tools. I crimp them using a drill press with a little cylindrical grindstone.

Answer (score 1):

Google "Micro-MaTch TE CONNECTIVITY" for this family of connectors.